I accidentally sent token to the currency contract, is it possible to get the tokens back?
Transaction Hash:
0x60edf1efc5d2b811a355bcbe5413825f46d770c42d46dbaa2b1d5b6a6fb5342a
Status:
Success
Block:
21307942
230 Block Confirmations
Timestamp:
45 mins ago (Dec-01-2024 01:25:11 PM UTC)
Transaction Action:
Transfer
5,187,976.1318716264507
($113.15)
PEPE
To
Pepe: PEPE Token
From:
0x4De88F11eB7E44A166d393c092a38A75b5d44864
Interacted With (To):
0x6982508145454Ce325dDbE47a25d4ec3d2311933
(Pepe: PEPE Token)
